# How can I redirect 7z-compressed content using LWP::UserAgent as an attachment

Tags: perl

I have a perl script which accepts incoming POST and PUT requests from other command line clients, gets the data (gzip) associated with each request and writes out to a seperate file.

I want to extend the script by adding redirect functionality.

Here is what I'm planning to do
* Once the data file is written, forward/redirect the file with the same headers(which we received from clients ) to another URL using LWP.

Please let me know about how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

LWP is a Web *client* library; I think you want `CGI`'s [`redirect` method](http://p3rl.org/CGI#GENERATING_A_REDIRECTION_HEADER) or similar.

Comment: Hi daxim,

I guess LWP can also be used from the command line.. any ideas how to use the CGI's redirect with gzip attachment and additional headers.

Comment: See [creating a standard HTTP header](http://p3rl.org/CGI#CREATING_A_STANDARD_HTTP_HEADER:) and [`Content-Disposition: attachment`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition). I don't think this attachment business to force a download is of much use, just deliver the file as-is with the appropriate `Content-Type` header.